# Make git ignore consecutive newlines

Tags: java, git, newline, git-commit

I'd like to track in git just the code (java), I'd like to have it ignore additions of multiple newline from previous commit (if no other code has changed) ex:

I'd like this

```
class MyApp{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length > 0) {
            for(String s : args){
                system.err.println("arg is "+s+"\n");
                }//end-for
            }//end-if
        }//end-met
    }//end-class
```

And this:

```
class MyApp{


    public static void main(String[] args) {


        if (args.length > 0) {
            for(String s : args){

                system.err.println("arg is "+s+"\n");

                }//end-for
            }//end-if


        }//end-met



}//end-class
```

to be considered the same (code should be seen as different only if non-newline character is added)

The goal of doing this is avoid replica of the same file when only noise has been added (if I search the file in git I'd like to get only when "actual" code changes has happened)

Comment: You could always write a script that removes newlines. I don't think git can do that.

Comment: I don't want to remove newlines (that usually are useful for understanding) I just do not want git to consider repeated newlines if newlines are the only changes to a specific file.

Comment: I'd recommend that you and your co-workers adopt a standard format for source files, and a tool that produces this format. Set up your editor to run this tool automatically on file-save. For Go source, see `gofmt`; for Python, consider `black`; for Rust, see `rustfmt`. I'm not a Java programmer and am not sure which tools are preferred for Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git doesn't provide a way to [ignore changes to a tracked file](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#ignore-tracked-files).

If you want to format the text before committing it, you can use a clean filter (specified in `.gitattributes` with the `filter` attribute) to automatically format it in whatever way you want.  You can see the documentation how to do this in the `gitattributes(7)` manual page.  Otherwise, there's no way to accomplish your goal with Git.